# Read the latest number from loop

Tags: php, while-loop

How can I read the latest number from the following code

```
<table  width="100" border="1" >
   <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999" >
     <td  >NO</td>
     <td  >Name</td>
     <td  >PBSID</td>
   </tr>

$query ="select * from stock ";
$hasil = mysql_query($query); 
$no=0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{ 
    $no++;
    if($x != $row[pbsid] )
    { 
        $no=1;
        echo "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
                  <td colspan=4 ><b> GROUP $row[pbsid]</b></td>
              </tr>";
    }

    $mo=count($no);
    echo "<tr><td>$no </td><td> $row[bnama]</td><td>$row[pbsid] </td></tr>";
    $x = $row["pbsid"];
}
```

The result:

---

```
===========
NO | NAME | GROUP
---------------------------------------
===========
GROUP 1
---------------------------------------
===========
1 | A | 1    
2 | B | 1    
3 | C | 1    
4 | D | 1
---------------------------------------
===========
GROUP 2
---------------------------------------
===========
1 | A | 2    
2 | B | 2    
3 | C | 2
```

I want to show the latest GROUP number, Group 1=4 and Group 2=3, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is only the last one no i.e 3 or 4 and 3?

Comment: Do You want only last row of group 1 and 2?

Comment: i want only last row number for every group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.*, c.count
FROM stock AS s
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT pbsid, COUNT(1) AS `count` FROM stock GROUP BY pbsid ) AS c
    ON s.pbsid = c.pbsid
```

Now you will have the count for each group, which is what it seems you really want.

If you'd prefer to do all the work in PHP for some reason, you could do it like this:

```
<table  width="100" border="1" >
   <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999" >
     <td  >NO</td>
     <td  >Name</td>
     <td  >PBSID</td>
   </tr>

$query ="select * from stock ";
$hasil = mysql_query($query); 
$no=0;

$counts = array();  // make an array of counts for each group, keyed by pbsid
$rows = array();  // put all the data from SQL into an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
    if (!isset($counts[$row[pbsid]]))
    {
        $counts[$row[pbsid]] = 0; // initialize it to 0
    }
    $counts[$row[pbsid]]++; // increment for each occurrence of a pbsid 
}

foreach ($rows as $row)
{ 
    $no++;
    if($x != $row[pbsid] )
    { 
        $no=1;
        echo "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
                  <td colspan=4 ><b> GROUP $row[pbsid]</b> Count = " . $counts[$row[pbsid]] . " </td>
              </tr>";
    }

    $mo=count($no);
    echo "<tr><td>$no </td><td> $row[bnama]</td><td>$row[pbsid] </td></tr>";
    $x = $row["pbsid"];
}
```

Although, I think it's much simpler to just have this information calculated in your query.

Comment: Hi elijah... i want to query from php code not from sql query.

Comment: I really think getting this info from SQL is a better way to do it but if you insist on php, see the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
$query ="select * from stock ";
$hasil = mysql_query($query); 
$no=0;
$latest = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{ 
$no++;
if($x != $row[pbsid] ){ 
$no=1;
echo "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
  <td colspan=4 ><b> GROUP $row[pbsid]</b></td>
</tr>";
}
$mo=count($no);
echo "<tr><td>$no </td><td> $row[bnama]</td><td>$row[pbsid] </td></tr>";
$x = $row["pbsid"];
$key = 'Group'.$row['pbsid'];
$latest[$key] = $no;
}
print_r($latest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table  width="100" border="1" >
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999" >
<td  >NO</td>
<td  >Name</td>
<td  >PBSID</td>
</tr>
$last_no = array();
$query ="select * from stock ";
$hasil = mysql_query($query); 
$no=0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{ 
$no++;
if($x != $row[pbsid] ){ 
$no=1;
echo "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
  <td colspan=4 ><b> GROUP $row[pbsid]</b></td>
</tr>";
}
$mo=count($no);
echo "<tr><td>$no </td><td> $row[bnama]</td><td>$row[pbsid] </td></tr>";
$x = $row["pbsid"];
$last_no[] = $no;
}
print_r($last_no);
```

Comment: I think this is not what he want?

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I had asked for that only the last one need or every no

Comment: i need only latest number from every group

Comment: i want to show the latest GROUP number, Group 1=4 and Group 2=3

Answer (score 0):

Change your query `$query ="select MAX(`no`),bnama, pbsid from yourtablename GROUP BY pbsid   ";`

Comment: i dont want to use sql query can i use with php query ?

Comment: i have another sql query with compleks code, i want implement this solution if any break my problem. just manipulate in php query or in function.

Comment: Why not show us your complex query, maybe this feature can be worked in easily. And maybe your complex query can be simplified a bit in the process. Maybe.